# OnClickListener for Dynamically created buttons

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I'm new to android Development and I hope you can help me.I created Buttons Dynamically ( Based on the contents of my Database). I also made onclicklistener for those buttons. The problem now is, If I click the buttons, Nothing happens. There is also no error shown in logcat. Why do you think this happened? Any response will be appreciated.

Here is my code on creating buttons:

```
final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        cursorCol = scoresDataBaseAdapter.queueCrit(mRowId);
        for(cursorCol.move(0); cursorCol.moveToNext(); cursorCol.isAfterLast()){
            int Id = Integer.parseInt(cursorCol.getString(cursorCol.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            Log.i("_id","_id : "+Id);
                String  CriteriaButton = cursorCol.getString(cursorCol.getColumnIndex("Criteria"));
               Log.i("CriteriaButton","CriteriaButton : " + CriteriaButton);


                 Button btn = new Button(this);
                    btn.setText("  " + CriteriaButton + "  "); 
                    btn.setId(Id);
                    btn.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    btn.setTextSize(12);
                    btn.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    btnlayout.addView(btn,params); 

                    btn.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(btn));}
```

Now after my OnCreate, I have the following method to set the onclicklistener

```
View.OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button button)  {
            return new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String criteria = button.getText().toString();
                    if ("Exams".equals(criteria)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exams Selected",2).show();  } 

                    else if ("Quizzes".equals(criteria)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Quizzes Selected",2).show();  } 

                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: Set a break point or add a Log.d() call in the `OnClickListener` to see if it is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String criteria = button.getText().toString();
```

to

```
String criteria = button.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this actually did it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onClick` method use `View` parameter of onClick method to get Text from pressed button as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button button = (Button)v;
    String selectedText = button.getText().toString();
    ....your code here
}
```